# While running Expo project getting should NOT have additional property 'nodeModulesPath'

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

Error: Problem validating fields in app.json. See https://docs.expo.io/workflow/configuration/
• should NOT have additional property 'nodeModulesPath'.

app.json

```
  "expo": {
    "name": "fludder",
    "slug": "fludder",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/Fludder-App-Icon-Android.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/LaunchScheen.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.fludder.fludderapp",
      "buildNumber": "1.0.0",
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSCameraUsageDescription": "This app uses the camera to record your answer.",
        "NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription": "This app uses your photo library to get recorded video.",
        "NSMicrophoneUsageDescription": "This app requires access to your microphone"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/Fludder-App-Icon-Android.png"
    },
    "description": "",
    "android": {
      "package": "com.fludder.fludderapp",
      "versionCode": 3,
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Show your `app.json`

Comment: I have added my app.json

Comment: Also ran npm i -g expo-cli but after execution it shows older version 4.0.13 instead of 4.4.3. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.
I upgraded the expo cli using `npm install -g expo-cli` command and the expo-cli version is 4.4.4 now. I can't see the error message anymore.

Comment: I have used yarn to update the project & resolved the issue. But now same error is coming while "expo build:android"